# How to print all lines between certain matching string to a different file in perl

Tags: perl

am fairly new to the perl scripting and need some help. below is my query:

I have a file which has contents like below:

```
AA ABC 0 0 
line1
line2
...
AA XYZ 1 1
line..
line..
AA GHI 2 2
line..
line...
```

Now I would like get all the lines between those lines which have the starting string/pattern `"AA"` and write them to files `ABC.txt`, `XYZ.txt`, `GHI.txt`, repsectively including the line `AA*`, for examples `ABC.txt` should look like

```
AA ABC 0 0
line1
line2...
```

and `XYZ.txt` should look like

```
AA XYZ 1 1
line..
line..
```

Hope am clear in this question and any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Sandy

Answer (score 3):

I presume you're asking for an algorithm since you didn't specify what you needed help with.

1. Declare a file handle for use for output.
2. While you haven't reached the end of the input file,

   1. Read a line.
   2. If it's a header line,

      1. Parse it.
      2. Determine file name.
      3. (Re)open the output file.
   3. Print the line to the output file handle.

---

Lest you be tempted to use one of the poor solutions that have been posted since I posted the above, here's the code:

```
my $fh;
while (<>) {
   if (my ($fn) = /^AA\s+(\S+)/) {
      $fn .= '.txt';
      open($fh, '>', $fn)
         or die("Can't create file \"$fn\": $!\n");
   }

   print $fh $_;
}
```

Possible improvements, all of which are easy to add:

- Check for duplicate headers. (`if -e $fn` is one way)
- Check for data before the first header. (`if !$fh` is one way)

Comment: Ran this from the command line against the OP's data in a file.  It produced only one file `1.txt` with the OP's last record in it.

Comment: @Kenosis, A set of parens were missing. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep one file open at a time...  When a line matches `XYZ`, then you open your `XYZ.txt` file and output the line.  You keep that file open (let's just say it's the handle `CURRENT_FILE`) and output each successive line to it until you match a new header line.  Then you close the current file and open another one.

My Perl is a extremely rusty, so I don't think I can provide code that compiles, but essentially it's something close to this.

```
my $current_name = "";

foreach my $line (<INPUT>)
{
    my($name) = $line =~ /^AA (\w+)/;
    if( $name ne $current_name ) {
        close(CURRENT_FILE) if $current_name ne "";
        open(CURRENT_FILE, ">>", "$name.txt") || die "Argh\n";
        $current_name = $name;
    }
    next if $current_name eq "";
    print CURRENT_FILE $line;
}

close(CURRENT_FILE) if $current_name ne "";
```

Comment: Thanks @amon for fixing my code =)  Years of C++ has stripped me of the ability to write Perl when I don't have an interpreter handy.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this one?

1: Get contents from the file (maybe using File::Slurp's read_file) and save to a scalar.

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);
my $contents = read_file($filename);
```

2: Have a regex pattern matching similar to this:

```
my @file_rows = ($contents ~= /(AA\s[A-Z]{3}\s+\d+\s+\w*)/);
```

3: If column 2 values are always unique throughout the file:

```
foreach my $file_row (@file_rows) {
    my @values = split(' ', $file_row, 3);
    write_file($values[1] . ".txt", $file_row);
}
```

3: Otherwise: Split the row values. Store them to a hash using the second column as the key. Write data to output files using the hash.

```
my %hash;
foreach my $file_row (@file_rows) {
    my @values = split(' ', $file_row, 3);
    if (defined $hash{$value[1]}) {
        $hash{$values[1]} .= $file_row;
    } else {
        $hash{$values[1]} = $file_row;
    }
}

foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    write_file($key .'txt', $hash{$key});
}
```

Comment: You go through quite bit of trouble just to keep the whole file in memory at all times? Also, I don't understant point No. 2, but it won't work the way you wrote it. Tip: it doesn't even compile. And you probably wanted to use `split` or something. And with the `split`s that you do use, you probably forgot a third argument of `3`. See [`perldoc -f split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm also thinking about the problem of keeping the whole file in memory at all times in Solution No. 1 (Maybe File::Slurp has an excellent way of doing it? Maybe..) so I would suggest Solution 2. I have 2 typos a while ago and added the third parameter of split. Haven't used split that way. Thanks! Edited the code now. What do you think of the second implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that looks for the pattern matching the start of each record.  When found, it loops through the data file's lines and builds a record until it finds the same pattern again or eof, then that record is written to a file. It does not check to see if the file already exists before writing to it, so it will replace ABC.txt if it already exists:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dataFile    = 'data.txt';
my $nextLine    = '';
my $recordRegex = qr/^AA\s+(\S+)\s+\d+\s+\d+/;

open my $inFH, '<', $dataFile or die $!;

RECORD: while ( my $line = <$inFH> ) {
    my $record = $nextLine . $line;

    if ( $record =~ $recordRegex ) {
        my $fileName = $1 . '.txt';

        while ( $nextLine = <$inFH> ) {
            if ( $nextLine =~ $recordRegex or eof $inFH ) {
                $record .= $nextLine if eof $inFH;

                open my $outFH, '>', $fileName or die $!;
                print $outFH $record;
                close $outFH;

                next RECORD;
            }

            $record .= $nextLine;
        }
    }
}

close $inFH;
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit**: This code replaces the original that was problematic.  Thank you, [amon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521179/amon), for reviewing the original code.

Comment: If a data line contains the sequence `AA`, it will be split in the middle. Consider changing `$/` to `"\nAA"`, although the first line will have to be special-cased. Deleting the record seperator is also known as `chomp`ing, so no need for using a substitution.

Comment: @amon - I greatly appreciate you critiquing the original code.  Strangely, didn't associate `$/` with `chomp` so thank you for bring it to my attention.  The original code was too problematic, so it's been replaced.  The above attempts to match the OP's record start, so is likely more robust.

Comment: Thanks Kenosis, this is helpful. I had a similar thing before, but your code does the job. the only issue i have right now is, if I have multiple line like

AA ABC 0 0
line1
line2

AA ABC 1 1
line3
line4

I would need both of them in same file, enabling me to update the already created abc.txt file rather than showing me line3 and 4 in file. Am trying some modifications myself, but any help from your side will be muchmore helpful.

Comment: @Santy - You're most welcome.  The regex worked on your data, producing all three text files, with names and contents as requested.  Since you've placed a `print` in the conditional and it isn't executed, that does suggest the regex isn't matching the start of records.  Since you're in full view of that data, perhaps you can successfully adjust the regex a little.  Let me know...

Comment: @Kenosis :  adjusted the regexp and worked perfect, the only issue i have right now is, if I have multiple line like AA ABC 0 0 line1 line2 AA ABC 1 1 line3 line4 I would need both of them in same file, enabling me to update the already created abc.txt file rather than showing me line3 and 4 in a new file.

Comment: @Santy - What distinguishes `AA ABC 1 1` from a 'header' line, i.e., one that begins a new file like "AA ABC 0 0"?  How do you recognize `AA ABC 1 1` as a line that should be saved into a file and not the start of ABC.txt?